# I am getting the error angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem trying to get angular working with this setup. I think I have the script referenced in the right location. Just isn't working for some reason. Here is the code...the error I am getting in Chrome is 'angular is not defined'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app = "demoApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

    <body>

    <div>
        <div data-ng-view="">
        </div>

    </div<


    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", []);


        demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/view1',
                    {
                        controller: 'SimpleController',
                        templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html'
                    })
                    .when('/view2',
                    {
                        controller: 'SimpleController',
                        templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html'
                    })
                    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });

        });



        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
            $scope.customers = [
            {name:'Nicholas Rodgers',city:'New Providence'},
            {name:'Michael Roker', city: 'Nassau Bahamas'},
            {name:'Jane Doe', city: 'Arizona California'}
            ];

            $scope.addCustomer = function(){
                $scope.customers.push(
                {
                    name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                    city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                });
            };
        })




    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is angular.min.js in the same directory as your html page?

Comment: inspect your page and look if in the network tab the angular.js is successfully downloaded or not

Comment: Suggestion: Put the `script` tag inside `<head>`.

Comment: One of your div tags isn't correct - it's `</div<` when it should be `</div>` - that could well stop the script tag from loading correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this link to get angular js file and check you have written wrong </div< tag

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```